# Get notified when a client connect to a WifiP2p group

Tags: android, android-wifi, net.p2p, wifi-direct

Is there any to way get a notification through a BroadcastReceiver when a client connects itself to a WifiP2p group created via [createGroup(..)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/p2p/WifiP2pManager.html) ?

Sounds like the

```
    - WIFI_P2P_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION
    - WIFI_P2P_PEERS_CHANGED_ACTION
    - WIFI_P2P_CONNECTION_CHANGED_ACTION and 
    - WIFI_P2P_THIS_DEVICE_CHANGED_ACTION
```

don't handle this.

Thank you.
Fab

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my own tests with createGroup(), I can tell that WIFI_P2P_PEERS_CHANGED_ACTION is actually notified when a client connects or disconnects.